# How to restrict a part of an object getting painted while texturing in blender

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

For example if I am painting a plane I only want its certain specified part to be painted. I tried using a box to cover the area which is not to be painted and when i start painting, the whole area gets painted. So I want to how paint only a certain specified area.

Comment: Enable the ''Face selection masking for painting'' option.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## **Masking using *'Face selection masking for painting'* option.**

[image]
[image]
Enable the ***Face selection masking for painting*** option. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to display the grid and select faces you want to paint using RMB.

---

## **Masking using painted *stencil*.**

[image]

In *Uv/Image Editor* add a new image, change its name and set its color to white.
[image]

Paint the areas where you want your texture to appear with a black color (create a *mask*). Save an image. Your mask is ready.
[image]

In ***Slots*** bookmark of a *Tool Shelf* check the ***Mask*** checkbox, choose the *UV map* you want to use (the one with the painted stencil displayed). Then select your painted mask image (click on an *image icon* under the *Stencil Image*). If you want to inverse the mask click on the *b&w square* under the *Visualisation*.
[image]

Add a new material and a texture (an image) you want to paint on. Now when you paint in a *Texture Paint* mode your brush strokes'll apear only in a black areas of your mask.
[image]

Comment: Your idea will work when I want to restrict certain faces which is not to be painted but how to restrict certain area within a face.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Hope this is what you're looking for :).