# Texture Painting goes through face

Tags: texture-painting

It seems that when I am painting, the paint goes through the face I have selected, onto other faces behind the selected face.

I am using 'Face selection masking for painting' and it still goes through onto the other face. Using different brushes such as fill yields the same undesired effect.

Why does it do this?

This is before I paint
[image: before]

This is after I paint.
[image: after]

Notice that the paint "bleeds" over into the other faces.

This is a tusk of an elephant btw

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39726/2517

Comment: @Tak that's what I am doing. It still goes through

Comment: Are [Occlude, Cull and Normal](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/texture_paint/options.html#project-paint) enabled on the Toolshelf > Options > Project Paint rollout ?

Comment: @MrZak I tried with those options on and off, both yield the same results.

Comment: @CraigDJones yes. read the question

Comment: Are you sure that texturing really affects not only areas you'd like to ? Probably UV map of the object is composed from multiple islands which are either intersecting or placed one near another and thus painting on small part of mesh affects several UV islands.